# Normal bundle of the diagonal

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

The normal bundle of a smooth submanifold $X \subset Y \subset R^N$ is defined as $N(X,Y)=\{(x,v) : x \in X, v \in T_xY, v \perp T_xX\}$. I want to show that $TX \cong N(\Delta,X\times X)$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal submanifold of $X \times X$. Intuitively to me, the points of $N(\Delta,X \times X)$, should be of the form $(x,v-v)$ but I have no idea how to show that.  I showed that the normal bundle is locally trivial, but I don't see if this can help in any way. Can someone help please?

Comment: What *is* $T_{(x,x)}\Delta$ as a subspace of $T_{(x,x)}(X\times X)$?

Comment: Is it something like $\{(x,x,v,v):v \in T_xX\}$?

Comment: Yes, so now you can you find the orthogonal complement?

Comment: Oh, yes, sure, the complement is just the set of all $(x,x,v,-v)$. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.